# How to convert a jQuery function with two function arguments into Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I want to convert a jQuery function written in JavaScript into Coffeescript, which gets two functions as parameters. I'm new to Coffeescript and I'm a little stuck here. The original function is something like:

```
$('#target').toggle(function() {
  alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
  alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
});
```

How does it look like in Coffeescript?

Comment: http://aaronrussell.co.uk/articles/using-coffeescript-with-jquery/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to see how something works in coffeescript in real time is to go over to the [official website](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and use the "Try Coffeescript" dropdown pane.  One way I found of getting it to output the exact same code as what you wanted was to do this:

```
$('#target').toggle ->
  alert 'First handler for .toggle() called.'
, ->
  alert 'Second handler for .toggle() called.'
```

Give it a try.  It may feel a bit odd typing code into a website, but *I've* certainly found it useful.

Comment: Thanks! It takes a little time to get used to CoffeeScript, but it's pretty sexy nevertheless!

Answer (score 7):

@genericdave's answer is correct. Here's an alternative in case the lack of parens confuses you like it does me:

```
$('#target').toggle(
    -> alert('First handler for .toggle() called.'),
    -> alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is certainly a little bit more readable (at least when you are new to Coffeescript).